# Convert Unix Timestamp to time zone?

Tags: php, unix, datetime, timezone, timestamp

I have a unix timestamp that is set to +5, but I'd like to convert it to -5, EST Standard time. I would just make the time stamp be generated in that time zone, but I'm grabbing it from another source which is putting it at +5.

Current Unmodified Timestamp Being Converted Into A Date

```
<? echo gmdate("F j, Y, g:i a", 1369490592) ?>
```

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Use [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [DateTimeZone](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php):

```
$dt = new DateTime('@1369490592');
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));
echo $dt->format('F j, Y, g:i a');
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong @John Surely this doesn't work? This method would use the systems (PHP Config) default timezone having not specified it when creating the instance of the DateTime object. Like [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17098897/234631). So when converting to America/Chicago it would be altered against the system timezone assuming it's not the same as +5 like the UNIX timestamp itself which he's trying to alter by ~10 zones?

Comment: @Stefan That is indeed wrong. Unix timestamps are always UTC. Some fun code samples:

    ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Los_Angeles');
    $now = time();
    $utc = new DateTime("@{$now}", new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
    echo "{$utc->format('c')}\n"; // 2014-08-27T15:24:09+00:00
    $utc = new DateTime("@{$now}");
    echo "{$utc->format('c')}\n"; // 2014-08-27T15:24:09+00:00
    ini_set('date.timezone', 'UTC');
    $utc = new DateTime("@{$now}", new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
    echo "{$utc->format('c')}\n"; // 2014-08-27T15:24:09+00:00

Comment: I'm going to to throw in some advice: if your UNIX timestamp is a variable, you have to use double quotes to make it work like this: `new DateTime("@$timestamp"); if you use single quotes or no quotes, you will get an error.

Answer (score 2):

An **easier** way to do that is:

While using `gmdate()`, add your time zone in seconds to unix_stamp in gmdate.

Consider my time zone is GMT+5:30. So *5 hr 30 min* in seconds will be *19800*

So, I'll do this:
 `gmdate("F j, Y, g:i a", 1369490592+19800)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function to **convert unix/gmt/utc timestamp to required timezone**, that might interest you.

```
function unix_to_local($timestamp, $timezone){
    // Create datetime object with desired timezone
    $local_timezone = new DateTimeZone($timezone);
    $date_time = new DateTime('now', $local_timezone);
    $offset = $date_time->format('P'); // + 05:00

    // Convert offset to number of hours
    $offset = explode(':', $offset);
    if($offset[1] == 00){ $offset2 = ''; }
    if($offset[1] == 30){ $offset2 = .5; }
    if($offset[1] == 45){ $offset2 = .75; }
    $hours = $offset[0].$offset2 + 0;

    // Convert hours to seconds
    $seconds = $hours * 3600;

    // Add/Subtract number of seconds from given unix/gmt/utc timestamp
    $result = floor( $timestamp + $seconds );

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As because edit queue for [John Conde's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16750466/1363799) is full I'll add more detailed answer.

From [`DateTime::__construct(string $time, DateTimeZone $timezone)`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php)

> The $timezone parameter and **the current timezone are ignored** when the
> $time parameter either is a UNIX timestamp (e.g. @946684800)…

This is the main reason why you should always specify timezone, even default, when creating `DateTime` objects from unix timestamp. See explained code inspired by [John Conde's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16750466/1363799):

```
$dt = new DateTime('@1369490592');

// use your default timezone to work correctly with unix timestamps
// and in line with other parts of your application
date_default_timezone_set ('America/Chicago'); // somewhere on bootstrapping time
…
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone(date_default_timezone_get()));

// set timezone to convert time to the other timezone
$dt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/Chicago'));

echo $dt->format('F j, Y, g:i a');
```