# Difficulty converting time between timezones

Tags: php, datetime, timezone

I'm trying to convert Midnight GMT into different time zones. We have a daily quiz that runs from midnight to midnight, and I'd like to be able to dynamically display the different time zones to people so it automatically changes with DST.

Following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098751/converting-a-time-to-a-different-timezone-with-php#answer-17098897) I came up with this code

```
$dateFormat = 'h:i a';
$date = new DateTime(gmdate('Y-m-d'), new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$tzWesternEurope = date($dateFormat);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
$tzCentralEurope = date($dateFormat);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Athens'));
$tzEasternEurope = date($dateFormat);
// ... And so for 17 different time zones around the world.
```

However it doesn't work. As you can see from this [eval.in](https://eval.in/159540) example all of the time zones show the same, and show the wrong time. What am I doing wrong?

I've tried changing `gmdate('Y-m-d')` to a time, `00:00` and `12am` but neither worked. I've tried using `UTC` instead of `GMT` as the base DateTimeZone, but again no difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're never actually using `$date`. You keep changing the timezone but then you ignore it and go straight to the `date()` function which is completely unrelated.

You need to use `DateTime::format()` to output the date in the format and timezone you want.

```
$dateFormat = 'h:i a';
$date = new DateTime(null, new DateTimeZone('GMT'));
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));
$tzWesternEurope = $date->format($dateFormat);
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin'));
$tzCentralEurope = $date->format($dateFormat);
```

Comment: GAH! Thank you. How could I be such an idiot. I've been staring at this for hours and didn't see that. Thank you.