# Convert php time() value to mysql format(24 hour format)

Tags: php, datetime

When the time is 2015-09-05 4:15:00 PM i run these codes:

```
$end=  time();
echo date('Y-d-m H:i:s',$end);
```

Expected output is :

> 2015-09-05 16:15:00

But i get

> 2015-09-05 12:15:00

How to get the expected output (24 hour format, I mean mysql format)?

Comment: check the time zone.

Comment: This likely has less to do with 24 hour format, but the configured timezone. (And local times don't belong in the database. Use GMT all the way through. Recalculate and format when displaying them instead.)

Comment: synchronize the server and mysql timezone or use 'NOW()' while inserting/updating the sql records.

Comment: what do u mean by 'Check the time zone'? Actually what i am to do?

Comment: [date_default_timezone_get()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-get.php)

Comment: possible duplicate of [converting a time to a different timezone with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17098751/converting-a-time-to-a-different-timezone-with-php)