# new datetime - only one instance at a time?

Tags: php, datetime

How can I display 3 different `datetime` objects on one page? The code below will only return the server date (first item) and dismiss all others.

Purpose of this script is to show the current date and time of the users location, including daylight saving time (meaning, the actual time of the specific place, not just GMT + whatever timezone they are supposedly in).

```
$server_datetime = new DateTime();  //located in America/New_York timezone - GMT-5
echo "Current Server DateTime: " . $server_datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo "<hr>";

$usersTimezone1 = 'Europe/London';  // GMT-0
$user_datetime1 = new DateTime(new DateTimeZone($usersTimezone1) );
echo "London User DateTime: " . $user_datetime1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo "<hr>";

$usersTimezone2 = 'Asia/Shanghai';  // GMT+8
$user_datetime2 = new DateTime(new DateTimeZone($usersTimezone2) );
echo "Shanghai User DateTime: " . $user_datetime2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo "<hr>";
```

Comment: Turn on error reporting

Comment: `Message: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string, object given` the DateTimeZone object should be the second parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Message: DateTime::__construct() expects parameter 1 to be string,
>   object given

the DateTimeZone object should be the second parameter.

```
$server_datetime = new DateTime();  //located in America/New_York timezone - GMT-5
echo "Current Server DateTime: " . $server_datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$usersTimezone1 = 'Europe/London';  // GMT-0
$user_datetime1 = new DateTime( 'now', new DateTimeZone($usersTimezone1) );
echo "London User DateTime: " . $user_datetime1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$usersTimezone2 = 'Asia/Shanghai';  // GMT+8
$user_datetime2 = new DateTime( 'now', new DateTimeZone($usersTimezone2) );
echo "Shanghai User DateTime: " . $user_datetime2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Comment: my hero... I knew it was something small ;)

Comment: but as per what _Sougata Bose_ said, turn on error reporting ;)

Comment: did that already, but my whole page died, resulting in a 500 error page, hence the error display was of no use. anyway, its sorted out now, thanks for the hand.

Comment: Well I'm glad it helped, can you please accept my post as the answer to your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
   $server_datetime = new DateTime();  //located in America/New_York timezone - GMT-5
    echo "Current Server DateTime: " . $server_datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    echo "<hr>";

    date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');
    $user_datetime = new DateTime();
    echo "London User DateTime: " . $user_datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    echo "<hr>";

    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Shanghai'); // GMT+8
    $user_datetime2 = new DateTime();
    echo "Shanghai User DateTime: " . $user_datetime2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

    echo "<hr>";
```

Output is:

```
    Current Server DateTime: 2017-03-14 06:22:59

    London User DateTime: 2017-03-14 05:22:59

    Shanghai User DateTime: 2017-03-14 13:22:59
```

Comment: Question: what if I want to base the usertime on the current server time? Eg. the server time '2017-01-01 13:00:00' is saved in my database, but now I want to display the equivalent time at that moment in timezone 'Asia/Shanghai', how would I do that? This doesnt seem to work:  `$user_datetime1 = new DateTime( $server_datetime, new DateTimeZone($usersTimezone1) );`

Comment: This may help you [converting a time to a different timezone with php](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17098897/2151290)

Answer (score 0):

@Armitage2k try this:

```
<?php
$server_datetime = new DateTime();
echo "Current Server DateTime: " . $server_datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo "<hr>";

$usersTimezone1 = 'Europe/London';  // GMT-0
$user_datetime1 = new DateTime();
$user_datetime1->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($usersTimezone1));
echo "London User DateTime: " . $user_datetime1->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo "<hr>";


$usersTimezone2 = 'Asia/Shanghai';  // GMT+8
$user_datetime2 = new DateTime();
$user_datetime2->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($usersTimezone2));
echo "Shanghai User DateTime:" . $user_datetime2->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');

echo "<hr>";
```